# javascript slideshow inside wp header not working

Tags: javascript

I just implemented a slideshow to the header of a WP site, but i can't get it to work

The code is hard coded inside the php site

see here:
http://dev.turnim.com/clients/lds/

I did upload all the javascript and css files, which the script came with and firebug is not showing me any errors.

I did check all the paths on the needed scripts/css and they are all ok

Anyone has an idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have either wrong paths to these libs or those libs dont exist. check them, so that they load with 200 OK

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://dev.turnim.com/clients/lds/wp-content/themes/spanisheyes/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
http://dev.turnim.com/clients/lds/wp-content/themes/spanisheyes/js/jquery/supersized.shutter.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://dev.turnim.com/clients/lds/slider/i.slider-1.0.min.js
```

Comment: there was a inconsistency with the filename of the last js file /i.slider-1.0.min.js should have been jquery.i.slider-1.0.min.js - I have just fixed thi8s, the other 2 missing fles shouldn't have anything to with the script i implemented, it's still not working

Comment: @UweKreuzahler, you should put ``jquery.js?ver=1.10.2`` before ``jquery.easing.min.js``. and ``genericons.css`` is also not available. http://dev.turnim.com/clients/lds/wp-content/themes/spanisheyes/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09